# Get and set IEEe 802.11 wifi protocol (a/b/g/n ...)

Tags: wifi

How can I see from the command line which IEEE 802.11 wifi protocol (a/b/g/n/ac/...) is used by the active wifi connection?

How can I force the connection to a specific mode?

I am using ubuntu linux (15.10) and an intel 5300 wifi card.

Comment: Which OS? If GNU/Linux, which distro? Which version of the OS?

Answer (score 2):

The 802.11 IEEE is a *standard* for wireless networking devices which defines a set of specifications for the physical and MAC layers of the **OSI model** (if you wish to learn more on networking you should *definitely*  get familiar with it).

Most versions normally operate around 2.4GHz/5GHz, and are generally backwards compatible.

The following command is the wireless-only variant of *ifconfig*:

```
iwconfig
```

On Ubuntu and Debian it is part of the *wireless-tools* package.

***ifconfig*** shows all the available (also virtual) network interfaces conforming to standards 802.x wireless and wired (802.3x is an example of a standard used in wired networking).
***iwconfig*** is exclusively for wireless interfaces such as 802.11x (some pre-802.11 are also supported).

These commands are also used to perform *advanced* configuration on your interfaces. Refer to their manual for more information.

**Edit**: since *iwconfig* is deprecated at the moment (but simple enough to query basic interface features) and no new significant updates are coming, I suggest you take a look at `iw` (which requires a fairly recent kernel >=3.0. You should have no problems running it on your Ubuntu 15.10 OS).

```
iw dev
```

This command returns all the available wireless interfaces. Then, you might want to run `iw dev <interface_name> info` or `iw phy <interface_phy> info`.
The first command shows brief information about the interface, while the second shows all the capabilities of the wireless device.